# array_unique with CakePHP foreach() - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, unique-key

I am trying to pull unique age id values from my array:

Sample of **Debugger::dump($rate_table_row['Age']);** :

```
...
array(
"id" => "15",
"name" => "55-59"
)

array(
"id" => "15",
"name" => "55-59"
)

array(
"id" => "15",
"name" => "55-59"
)
...
```

**I am trying to process this by doing such:**

```
$uniqueAgeArray = array_unique($rate_table_row['Age']);
print_r($uniqueAgeArray);
```

The **$uniqueAgeArray** is **not unique in any sense**. All results are printed as such:

```
 Array ( [id] => 15 [name] => 55-59 )

 Array ( [id] => 15 [name] => 55-59 )

 Array ( [id] => 15 [name] => 55-59 )
```

I am trying to eliminate any duplicate "id" or "name" from this array.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The answer to your question is "array_unique does not work that way", see @viktor 's answer You might mean to ask how to filter the doubles?

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP documentation for array_unique](http://php.net/array_unique):

> Note: Note that array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional
>   arrays.

So you need to use another approach, like looping through the array and storing only values not encountered before.

```
// Temporary index of unique id's and names
$_index = array(
    'id'   => array(),
    'name' => array(),
);

// Final array with unique values
$uniqueAgeArray = array();

foreach ($rate_table_row['Age'] as $item)
{
    // Check if id or name is already present
    if (isset($_index['id'][$item['id']]) || isset($_index['name'][$item['name']]))
        continue;

    // Store in result
    $uniqueAgeArray[] = $item;

    // Store values in index
    $_index['id'][$item['id']] = true;
    $_index['name'][$item['name']] = true;
}
```

[Codepad test case and example](http://codepad.org/ooomzwzH)

Comment: I've tried about every suggestion I could find on line and I cannot get the results I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I tested the code and added a link to a codepad case. For me, it filters out duplicate values as you described ("eliminate any duplicate id or name"). If this is not what you're trying to achieve, please be a little more specific.

Comment: You tried every suggestion, but also above? looks valid to me?

Comment: The above solution did not work. I solved this entirely w/out array_unique(). I think my original question might not have been clear enough, but thanks for the replies and assistance.

Comment: Another part of the problem was my array was 3 levels deep, and I did not indicate that in my original question. I probably wasted your time and my time. I need to better prepare my questions in the future.